System Integration and System testcases in Rhapsody
how can we write my testcases in Rhapsody and link them to models defined in rhapsody itself. How can I write testcases for system and system Integration testlevels as well for AUTOSAR systems?
We are expecting our testcases for these higher testlevels can be written in the form of rhapsody models or any sequence diagram or any flowchart.
Recommendations on good books about Model Based Testing in rhapsody are also appreciated:)
